# How to make a 16 x 16 inline-block grid using a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to automatically generate a 16 by 16 grid of square `div` using a loop inside a loop. I've created this two classes:

```
.square {
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

and

```
.line {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 800px;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

and I have this function:

```
$('#b1').click(function() {
   for(i=0; i<16; i++) {
       $('#pixelgrid').append('<div class="line">');
       for(j=0; j<16; j++) {
           $('#pixelgrid').append('<div class="square">'+j+'</div>');
       }
    $('#pixelgrid').append('</div>');
   }
});
```

The grid shows up somewhat correctly but the `square` divs are not displaying `inline-block` as I intended.

How can I make them display properly as `inline-block` inside the `line` divs?

Is there another, more efficient way of doing this?

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5HV6s/1/

Comment: What do you mean by "they are not displaying as `inline-block` " ? How did you expect them to look like?

Comment: It's showing correctly for me. Maybe resize the window bigger so it doesn't wrap. If wrapping is your issue, try adding `#pixelgrid {white-space:nowrap;}`

Comment: You aren't appending the blocks inside the line... just after the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your `display:inline-block;` to `display:table-cell;` for `.square` and moved the alignment to `.square` as well.

As ***@Danko*** pointed out in the comments, you do not need the `.line` class at all.

I've also redone your jQuery to make it slightly more optimized (if that even matters).

---

### JQUERY

```
var $grid = $('#pixelgrid');

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
{
    var row = '<div>';
    
    for (j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        row += '<div class="square">' + j + '</div>';
    
    row += '</div>';

    $grid.append(row);
}
```

---

### CSS

```
body 
{
    background:#000;
}
.square 
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
    background-color: white;
}
```

---

### ***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ThJN4/)***

Comment: Nice way .. notice you don't need the line. Block squares aren't inside that.

Comment: Even if you don't need to style it, there are benefits to marking that outer div with the class "line" . . . each row is a distinct, but common unit.  Having a way to identify each item in that collection without having to derive it, could be helpful.

Comment: @talemyn - That's true as well.  The OP can make that distinction for themselves.

Comment: This is indeed much more elegant and efficient. Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: @Hubologist - No problem, glad you are happy with it!

Answer (score 1):

You may get some funny results using the `append()` function the way that you are (separately, adding the opening and closing tags for the "line" div) . . . instead, try creating the whole div for each line and appending the squares into it, like this:

```
var $newLine;
$('#b1').click(function() {
    for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
        $newLine= $('<div class="line"></div>');
        $('#pixelgrid').append($newLine);

        for (j=0; j<16; j++) {
            $newLine.append('<div class="square">'+j+'</div>');
        }
    }
});
```

After testing that code and applying your styles, locally, I was able to see a properly formatted grid.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to center the content try this. Use the `line-height` to center the text vertically and apply the `text-align: center` on the `.square` class:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5HV6s/3/)**

```
.square {
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:2.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.line {
    width: 800px;
}
body {
    background:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three things you need to do:

1. It's a table, **use a `<table>`**
2. **Cache** jQuery objects/selectors
3. Append to the DOM only **after you are done**

### Here's the code and the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5HV6s/4/)

```
var $table = $('#pixelgrid');
var html = [];
var row, col;
for(row=0; row<16; row++) {
    html.push('<tr class="line">')
    for(col=0; col<16; col++) {
        html.push('<td class="square">'+col+'</td>');
    }
    html.push('</tr>');
}
$table.append(html.join(''));
```

### CSS:

```
body {
    background:#000;
}
#pixelgrid {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

.square {
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't assume that a `<table>` is the best way to go here . . . without knowing his intentions for the grid, I would simply offer it up as an alternative, not *the* solution.